# SQLAlchemy relationships: more than one self-referenced columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is an sqlalchemy object

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee"
    # Columns
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    representative_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    affiliate_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))

    # Relatonships
    representative = relationship("Employee", ????)
    parent = relationship("Employee", ????)
    affiliate = relationship("Employee", ????)
```

How to configure the relationships in the right way if an employee can have, 0 or 1 parent, affiliate and representative? Do know these three are different ones. DB - MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how do to it by myself:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee"
    # Columns
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    representative_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    affiliate_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))

    # Relatonships
    representative = relationship("Employee", 
                         primaryjoin="Employee.representative_id==Employee.id", 
                         remote_side=[id])
    parent = relationship("Employee",
                         primaryjoin="Employee.parent_id==Employee.id", 
                         remote_side=[id])
    affiliate = relationship("Employee",
                         primaryjoin="Employee.affiliate_id==Employee.id", 
                         remote_side=[id])
```